# Two usages of "could"

Tags: modal-verbs

> ## Scene 1
>
> Bad guy (Raymond Sellars): Alex, honestly, I mean you no harm. If I wanted to, I could have killed you a long time ago. I just aim this right at your head and blow it off.
>
> Alex's wife: Sellars, please! Don't!
>
> Bad guy: I mean, if I wanted to, I could just aim this at your little family and I could just kill them too. And really, there's nothing you **could** do about it because, let's face it, you're a robot.
>
> ## Scene 2
>
> Bad guy (Raymond Sellars): What's clear is that with just one system in place, we've cut crime by 80%. Just imagine if we put, I dunno, let's say 100 systems in place. And then, I want you to ask yourself, why are you holding us back?
>
> Senator: Is that your plan?
>
> TV show host(Pat): Thank you, Senator. And thank you, Raymond.
>
> Bad guy: Thank you, Pat.
>
> TV show host: Well, there you have it. Who **could** argue with that? Which begs the question. Has the US Senate become pro-crime?
>
> *--Robocop 2014*

Mr. Modal comes back again.

I have figured out all of "could" in this movie except for these two. Why not use "can" or "would" instead?

For the first one, if that "could" followed the previous ones, the sentence would be "there **would be** nothing you can do about it", I suppose.

For the second, is the sentence the same as "Who **would be able to** argue with that?

Comment: I read the first one as a hypothetical usage (following that *if I wanted to*), and the second one as a less definite form of *can*.

Comment: For the first one, we think alike. But like I said, the sentence should be "there would be nothing you can do about it". @Damkerng T

Comment: *Could* can be used in that sense. I think you probably have PEU. If you have it, try 122.6.

Comment: I know that. You see, I put that point even in my question. I am asking why "is" is not shifted into "would be". @Damkerng T

Comment: I believe that saying "Who would be able to ..." is less idiomatic than "Who could ...", though I wouldn't go so far to say that people don't say "would be able to". You might also find this unfair [Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=who+could+argue%2Cwould+be+able+to+argue&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwho%20could%20argue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwould%20be%20able%20to%20argue%3B%2Cc0) interesting. To be fair, "would be able to argue" should be compared to "could argue", and yet "who could argue" obviously outnumbers the other.

Comment: You are evading the issue. What I mean here is that "could” means "would be able to", but apparently we don't normally use the latter. It's just a way of paraphrase. As you said, the second one is a less definite form of can. Can we just use "might" instead? @Damkerng T

Comment: Hmm... I might get into this too deep. But iirc, FumbleFinger answered a similar question (can we use *would* or *might* instead of *could*), and I think the answer (or the comment, I'm not sure) was generally you can. I believe you can do the same here too. But it would be strange to say *might* when you want to say *could* and say *could* when you want to say *might*.

Comment: Books on grammar say may/might/could all mean factual possiblity and they are, more often than not, interchangeable. @Damkerng T

Comment: That's quite true, *when* it's used to express a possibility. I think we've discussed this before.

Comment: "And really, there's nothing you could do about it because, let's face it, you're a robot" = "And really, there's nothing you [would be able to] do about it [in that hypothetical situation] because, let's face it, you're a robot".  It's talking about the listener's **actual** capabilities ("there IS", "because you ARE a robot") in a **hypothetical** situation ("COULD do").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, "there's nothing you **could** do about it," *could* is *can* in the conditional mood.  The conditional is used because the entire situation is hypothetical.  Compare with this non-hypothetical example:

> Bad guy: I will aim this at your little family and I just kill them too. And really, there's nothing you **can** do about it because, let's face it, you're a robot.

---

The second example is a bit trickier to analyze, I think.  Your interpretation — "Who **would be able to** argue with that?" — is correct.  Using *could* instead of *can* expresses doubt.  "Who *can* argue with that?" would be closer to a challenge — an invitation for someone to come forth and try to argue.  By saying "Who *could* argue with that?", the speaker is expressing that he thinks nobody would succeed.

I think that the [second definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/could) explains that usage — *could* is used to express conditional ability.

Comment: I thought so, but why isn't the main verb "is" changed to conditional mood? @200_success

Comment: And what would that sentence look like?

Comment: "There would be nothing you can do about it."

Comment: So why shift the verb in the sub-clause, not the main verb? I thought the main verb is always preferred.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't read that carefully.  "There would be nothing you could do about it" would be acceptable.  "There would be nothing you can do about it" would be a verb form disagreement.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I think I missed that *'s* the first time we discussed your questions. For me, "[T]here's nothing you could do about it" is fine because *could* is hypothetical, but *'s* (or *is*) is not in the hypothetical thinking. For the speaker, it's so true (or real) that *there would be* is unnecessary (and I think it's less likely to be said). For a similar usage, try thinking of telling a story to a kid, "You want a tale? Here is one. This tale begins with 'Once upon a time, there was a farm boy who fell in love with a princess'."

Comment: That is exactly what I was asking. I have no problem with the rest. I thought you had caught it in the first place. @Damkerng T

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I really did misread it. It might be because only the *would be* part was marked bold, but not *can*; or it might be because it didn't look like a question; or it was because you didn't mention "is" or "'s" in your question; or maybe it was just me. What happened was somehow I really did misread it.

Comment: As for the second example, 200_success agreed with me, but you didn't. What would be your reasons? @Damkerng T

Comment: Why do you think I don't agree with 200_success?

Comment: I misunstood your comment. You said could was a less definite form of can. But in which sense, less possiblity or less ability? @Damkerng T

Comment: Saying "less definite" form of *can* could mean either. I use the term the same way Swan used it, I think.